# How should I move or delete files in a Yeoman Generator?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm building a generator that in part includes scaffolding from another project created with `exec`. Depending on user input I need to move or delete parts of this scaffolding.

Right now I'm doing it with node's `fs.child_process.spawn` and `shelljs`, but seeing as the Yo generator has `mkdir`, `write`, `template`, and `copy`, I'm wondering if there's a Yo way to move or delete files and directories.

Answer (score 5):

I just use [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) like this:

```
MyGenerator.prototype.removeDir = function removeDir () {
    var cb = this.async(),
        self = this;

    rimraf('path/to/dir', function () {
        self.log.info('Removing dir');
        cb();
    });
};
```

Remember to add `rimraf` as a dependency in your `package.json` file. Not sure if there's a built-in function for this but this one's been working fine for me so far.

Comment: That's a good way too. Upvoted you but letting this remain unanswered until there's a Yeoman api way of doing it.

Comment: There should be a built in function, I'm wondering why it's not documented though specially since RC 1.0 is out now.

Answer (score 2):

Yeoman now supports this via the `fs` API, which is an in memory filesystem implementation.

`this.fs.move('source/file', 'dest/file');
this.fs.copy('source', 'dest');`

[File System Docs](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html)

Answer (score 2):

Still not documented, but this is the delete method (works for me):

```
this.fs.delete('file/to/delete');
```

Link: [Yeoman issue 1505](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1505)